# Extract and send xmls from large xml file to api endpoint in jmeter

Tags: xml, jmeter

I have received 20 large xml files. These large xml file contains, multiple small xmls in it. on top of the large xml file is a header and then comes small xmls.
There are around 2500 small xmls.

I have a test in jmeter and now i dont know how can i send these small xml files to the api endpoint.
if i do it manually then is huge time involved.
is there any way to extract these small xmls from this large xml file and then send these small xmls to endpoint.

what i have tried is that in my test plan i use ${__FileToString} and i am trying to read the xml from the local drive. but problem is that it is taking all content of large xml and not specific small xmls. please advise. what

[large xml file with small xmls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg94x.png)

[test plan http request file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmW3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to do this one by one, i.e. one request per "small" XML file you can:

   - Use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler with `file` protocol to read the "large" file from the file system
   - Use [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations) to fetch these "small" files into JMeter Variables
   - Use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate each and every of these "small" files and send a request per file
2. If you need to do this "in one shot" you can use [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) custom function to remove this header/footer

Comment: i tried but i do not understand how to retrieve complete xml. the webpage does not mentions that. adding pictures of xml and the testplan setup